# Image is not positioned to center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

[image]

I want to display an image in a table in the center of a cell, but this is what i get. My image covers the complete cell rather than being placed in the center of the cell . I am using an img-responsive class for image and table-responsive for table both from the bootstrap file.
Further, whenever I load the page, i get one of the following outputs randomly with absolutely no change in the code.
Why does this happen??
In both the cases image, image will be seemed to be positioned to the left side of the column, how do I correct it so that image is positioned in the center.
Following is the code

```
<div class="table-responsive inside_content ps-container" style="margin-bottom: 50px">
<style>
    th,td{
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
<table id="event" class="table table-striped table-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Serial No.</th>
          <th>Section</th>
          <th>TimeStamp</th>
          <th>Archive_Status</th>
          <th>Event Picture</th>
          <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
                    <tr>
            <td>
                test1                </td>
            <td>
                Event3                </td>
            <td>
                2015-01-08 19:41:45                </td>
            <td>
                0                </td>
            <td>
                <a class="event_group1" href="http://localhost/IOCLALL/IOCLbackend/../IOCLfrontend/images/events/WWW.YTS_.RE_.jpg">
                    <img alt="No Image" class="img-responsive" style="max-width:145;max-height: 208px" src="http://localhost/IOCLALL/IOCLbackend/../IOCLfrontend/images/events/WWW.YTS_.RE_.jpg" />
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="http://localhost/IOCLALL/IOCLbackend/index.php/start/deleteevent?id=2" onclick="return del();"><span class="fa fa-fw fa-trash" ></span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="http://localhost/IOCLALL/IOCLbackend/index.php/start/editevent?id=2" onclick=""><span class="fa fa-fw fa-edit" ></span></a>
            </td>
        </tr>



    </tbody>
</table>

</div>
```

Comment: Also use class .center-block.

Comment: Nopes, that didn't work either.

Comment: if the current suggestions are not working, could you provide us with a demo/more code so that we can see the issue

Comment: What I believe there is something with img-responsive and table-responsive but i am not able to put my finger on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must treat the **TD** like you would treat a **P**,
add a **text-align:center** to the **TD** and a **display:inline-block** to the image

```
<td style="text-align: center;">
    <img style="display: inline-block;" />
</td>
```

Comment: That is precisely correct, but problem is what ever property i put here is somehow overridden by the bootstrap classes. I do not see these property in the google inspect element.

Comment: You can allways overwrite it with your own class <img class="this-class" />, .this-class { display: inline-block; }

Comment: Or in last case use the !important to force it, .this-class{ display: inline-block !important; }

Answer (score 0):

```
<td style="text-align: center;">
```

add css to that td to align text in the center, it should apply for the image as well

Comment: That is already done for the whole table. Look at the other cells and text is aligned to the center

Answer (score 0):

Add align="center" to the cell  .

Eg.

`<td align="center">
   <img src="...`

Comment: just for the sake of it: display: table; margin: 0 auto;

Answer (score 0):

how about adding 
display:inline / inline-block;
margin:0px auto;

I hope it will answer your question